# Understanding amplitude-time peaks in one dimensional reflection and transmission of sound waves

Tags: impedance, transmission-line, reflection

There is a one dimensional system of interfaces with a transducer sending and receiving sound wave (Plane wave) normal to the interface boundary. The system consists of two mediums, medium 1 & medium 2, with acoustic impedance of \$Z_1\$ & \$Z_2\$, thickness of \$D_1\$ & \$D_2\$ and sound speed \$C_1\$ & \$C_2\$, respectively. The arrangement of the system is as follows:

[image]

The arrangement has a transducer with the mediums lined in the order as in the image and at the end there is an absorber. This system can be treated as a transmission line problem/ model.

The amplitude vs time graph of the sound pulse is shown in the image below:

[image]

**How are these peaks in the image marked with the respective reflection and transmission factors?**

As per my understanding: The first peak (Blue) in the first (A vs t) graph is the amplitude of the pulse generated in the transducer, which is the biggest peak in comparison to others. Second peak that follows after time \$\frac{d_1}{c_1}\$ is the transmitted pulse with the transmission factor of \$\frac{2Z_2}{Z_1\:+\:Z_2}\$ between interface of medium 1 & 2. Similarly, between medium 2 & 1, after time \$(\frac{d_1}{c_1}+\frac{d_2}{c_2})\$, the transmitted pulse has a transmission factor of \$(\frac{2Z_2}{Z_1\:+\:Z_2}*\frac{2Z_1}{Z_2\:+\:Z_1})\$ which is the product of the transmission factor from 1st interface (incident pulse) and transmission factor in medium 2. 
what about the last peak and the peak in second graph?

In third graph, I suppose the peaks represent the refection coefficients with the second peak inverted due to phase shift as \$Z_1 < Z_2\$.